# ConcurrentQueue c#, inexact result?

Tags: c#

I would like to ask about queue in c#
If ConcurrentQueue is safe thread, why the result of this code is ~98 k?
Do I something wrong?

```
class Program
{
    static int sum = 0;
    static ConcurrentQueue<int> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<int>();

    static void Main()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            queue.Enqueue(1);
        }

        Task t1 = Task.Run(() => Calculate());
        Task t2 = Task.Run(() => Calculate());

        Task.WaitAll(t1, t2);

        Console.WriteLine($"Sum = {sum}");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void Calculate()
    {

        int result;
        while (queue.TryDequeue(out result))
        {
            sum += result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `sum += result` is not an atomic operation and can be executed by both threads concurrently.

Answer (score 7):

This is the problem:

```
sum += result;
```

That's not atomic. It's effectively:

```
var tmp = sum;
tmp += result;
sum = tmp;
```

What do you think will happen if both of your threads reach the middle line at the same time?

You can fix this with [`Interlocked.Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33821kfh(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
while (queue.TryDequeue(out result))
{
    Interlocked.Add(ref sum, result);
}
```

Note that this has nothing to do with using `ConcurrentQueue` - you'd see the same thing if your loop had just been:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++)
{
    sum++; // Just as bad...
}
```

Comment: May I Replace Interlocked with lock?

Answer (score 2):

Its because of

```
sum += result;
```

This is not thread safe. Multiple threads can hit this LoC concurrently and assign the same value.

You could fix this with a `lock` statement (*among other ways*).